# When I type $ gcc into the mac Terminal I get a "-bash: gcc: command not found"

Tags: macos, gcc, command-line, terminal

However, it works when I type:

```
$ gcc-4.2
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have a C++ compiler installed?

Comment: Have you installed Xcode and the command line developer tools? also for OSX you might want to use clang instead

Answer (score 0):

Find where `gcc-4.2` is installed and go into that directory:

```
$ cd $(which gcc-4.2)
```

Check if there is a gcc symlink:

```
$ ls gcc
```

If there isn't one, create it:

```
$ ln -s gcc-4.2 gcc
```

Comment: how can I find out where gcc-4.2 is installed? It doesn't appear when i search for it in Finder.

Comment: ok, but even after entering these commands I still get "-bash: gcc: command not found" after typing "gcc"...

Comment: @user1715271 That should work; are you sure you have done everything to the letter?

Answer (score 0):

I got it: all was well after I installed **command line tools** in Xcode > Preferences > Downloads.